# Gradle compile and run

Tags: java, gradle

Is it possible to split a "gradle run" task into a compile task and a run task, so that subsequent runs will invoke the same compiled binaries (jar Java) for consistency.

Comment: AFAIK Gradle already does artifact caching and won't build again if everything is up to date. It already defines compile and probably run steps. If you hook your run task up correctly in the Gradle life cycle, it should work out of the box. What problems are you seeing? Can you include your build script?